# Parsing Data chuck of a .wav file in c++

Tags: c++, wav, sha1

I am using a SHA1 Hash to verify the authenticity of a `.wav` file. The SHA1 function I am using takes in three parameter:

1. a pointer to the authentication file with `.auth` extension
2. The data buffer read from the `.wav` file  (which must be less than 42000 bytes in size)
3. The length of the buffer

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < size_buffer; i++) {
    DataBuffer[i] = fgetc(WavResult);
}
util_sha1_calculate(&AuthContext, DataBuffer, size_buffer);
```

How can I set a read function to read 42000 bytes, transfer the data to `util_sha1_calculate(&AuthContext, DataBuffer, size_buffer)`, and start from the position it left off when the loop is repeated, and proceed to read then next 42000 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your shown `for` loop inside of another outer loop that runs until EOF is reached, eg:

```cpp
size_t size;
int ch;

while (!feof(WavResult))
{
    size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_buffer; i++) {
        ch = fgetc(WavResult);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        DataBuffer[size++] = (char) ch;
    }
    if (size > 0)
        util_sha1_calculate(&AuthContext, DataBuffer, size);
}
```

However, you should consider replacing the inner `for` loop with a single call to `fread()` instead, eg:

```cpp
size_t nRead;
while ((nRead = fread(DataBuffer, 1, size_buffer, WavResult)) > 0)
{
    util_sha1_calculate(&AuthContext, DataBuffer, nRead);
}
```